# how can i give the path to export a dataframe to excel file in ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I give the full path to export a `Dataframe` to excel file

```
xport_excel = df.to_excel('home\desktop\python\export_dataframe.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

I have a DataFrame df and I have to export that dataframe df into excel file.

Comment: What's the error that you are getting? Change the `\` to '/' and see if it works..

Comment: pandas rely on `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` packages to export `pandas.DataFrame` object to a excel file. You can install them via `pip install openpyxl` or `pip install xlsxwriter`. Nonetheless, you did not stated why you cannot export, please describe the issue more clear.

Comment: ImportError: No module named openpyxl.workbook

Comment: you may have to install module `openpyxl`

Comment: @null i don't know why i'm not able to export reason can be may be i am not specifying the path in exact way, or i have not installed openpyxl and xlsxwriter, should i import something please tell me, now i have installed openpyxl

Comment: now getting this error,
ImportError: No module named xlwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=result1[['StoreID', 'BatchID', 'Quantity', 'ProductID']]   


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```